# How to stop a non-killable process on a Ubuntu VM running on windows 10?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, process, kill

On windows 10 I have a Oracle VM VirtualBox running with Ubuntu 20.04.5 and sometimes an application (started with `sudo`) just "hangs". I am not able to kill the job using

```
kill -9 <process_id>
```

because this `kill` process will also hang.

Is there any other way to stop such a process without force-stopping the VM?

Output from `ps -ef`:

```
root        3207    3166  0 10:26 pts/1    00:00:00 sudo ./isp_cli 79 sjb50_bootloader_secondary_v0.1.0m_kja
root        3208    3207  0 10:26 pts/1    00:00:00 ./isp_cli 79 sjb50_bootloader_secondary_v0.1.0m_kjar_190
```

The command `ps -Al` shows

```
4 S     0    1811    1714  0  80   0 -  5142 -      pts/0    00:00:00 sudo
4 D     0    1812    1811  0  80   0 -  1634 -      pts/0    00:00:00 isp_cli
```

It is an application to communicate via USB <-> CAN with some hardware device. And for some testing (interrupting some communication process) it will always fail running a second time. And it becomes quite cumbersome to restart the VM in each of these cases.

I also tried to use

```
sudo pkill -9 -f isp_cli
sudo killall -9 isp_cli
sudo kill -hup 1811
sudo kill -15 1811
```

but these commands also were unable to stop the actual blocking process, and hang as well.

I further tried to get some more information about the process, but even if I try

```
sudo cat /proc/1916/stack
```

this also hangs. No output, no return to the terminal.

Comment: Any process waiting in device will usually be unkillable. This is a poor question though as you are giving us no info on which process is failing. Do not drip feed info.

Comment: What additional information do you need?

Comment: How about output from `ps`, how about which devices are connected and what are expected to be connected. How about what the process is actually trying to achieve. How about info on the host as to whether it is using network shares.

Comment: The application is used to write firmware to a microcontroller using CAN. The first two times or so when using the application just works fine, then when running a third time it hangs. Also see updated question.

Comment: @Alex, thanks for providing details. Could you also please include what you've looked into so far? Any [research you've done](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)? Please include anything you've tried so far (and which didn't work) as then others won't spend time suggesting it as a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, your `ps` output does not indicate the process state (Running, Waiting, I/O Wait, …). To clarify what Bib means: If a process is waiting for an I/O system call, it cannot be killed.

Comment: Of course it can. I just stop the VM which is just software, and it is being killed. I do not need to reboot the host machine. But my question is: Can I kill this possible I/O wait without restarting the VM all the time?

Comment: We are talking about not being able to kill it from within the vm, not killing it by bringing the vm down.

Comment: @Alex stopping the VM is like pulling the plug of a real PC. (Depending on how exactly you do this.)

Comment: @Bib Yes I would prefer to be able to kill that process without shutting down the VM.

Comment: Seems like it is hanged up by a interrupt related to device. Not much possible to do in that case but removing connection to the device (unplug).

Comment: @pbies Disconnecting the device also does not help. Process still not killable.

Comment: Please include the output of `ps -Al`. Try `kill -hup` and `kill -15`. Try also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386800/17660).

Comment: @harrymc Question updated with more details.

Comment: The `D` status means that the process is in [Uninterruptible sleep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_(system_call)#Uninterruptible_sleep), and this name does mean what it says. I think that the link in my previous comment is sort of your last chance.

Comment: @harrymc Ok thanks, I will check it out next time this happens

Comment: Unkillable processes in I/O wait are usually caused by either stuck hardware or a buggy device driver.  If unplugging the device (virtually or physically) doesn't reset the connection and release the process, I'd go with buggy device driver.

Answer (score 0):

The `D` status means that the process is in
[Uninterruptible sleep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_(system_call)#Uninterruptible_sleep)
and this name really does mean what it says.

You might try the solution from the post
[unkillable/unstoppable normal user process, how to forcedly control it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386776/unkillable-unstoppable-normal-user-process-how-to-forcedly-control-it)
I reproduce below the
[answer by Aquarius Power](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386800/17660).

> I can avoid rebooting using the commands below:
>
> ```
> sudo cgcreate -g cpu:/cpulimited
> sudo cgclassify -g cpu:cpulimited 2315444 #the `find` pid
> cd /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpulimited
> echo 1000000 |sudo tee cpu.cfs_period_us
> echo 1000 |sudo tee cpu.cfs_quota_us #cant be less than 1000 as I tested
> ```
>
> read the full explanation for cpu.cfs_quota_us at
> [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-cpu.html#sect-cfs),
> from this [tip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193996/30352)
>
> The cgroup magic works on such unkillable process!